# Compilation process for C++ application?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation

I have been programming for 2 years now and always have faced difficulty when dealing with the compilation process.
I did not study Computer Science during my Engineering, but necessity drove me towards learning C++.
I tried understanding the compilation process from some blogs, but they were always in a language I could not understand.
So I searched this site for a similar question, but could find none.
So I would like to know how the text from a .cpp is converted to a binary executable?

Comment: With all the fluff removed, your question boils down to: "How is the text from a .cpp file converted to a binary executable?" - which is far too broad for stackoverflow. Try wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler - or google, or find a book..

Comment: This question would take many chapters to explain.

Comment: @unxnut language is C++ and platform is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the preprocessor runs first resolving all your `#includes`, `#defines`, *etc* with simple text substitution.  Then the compiler creates a compilation-unit for each `.cpp` file which pretty much boils everything down to machine-code except for "connections" or *linkages* between shared data and functions. There may be many levels of optimisation for speed and/or space performed. This is repeated for all your `.cpp` files. Finally, a link phase ties all these compilation-units and the libraries they use together into an executable.